# Navigation robot Pioneer

Tags: ros, navigation, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We use the Pioneer 3dx with kinect sensor. We must reach a red object in a unknown map, then we need to position the robot in front of the red object at a given distance.
We do not know how to do, especially for positioning at a given distance from the object.
Please help us!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12958/navigation-robot-pioneer/) by [es](https://answers.ros.org/users/1764/es/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like a good use for visual servoing; write a vision algorithm to detect red things, turn until it's in the center of your field of view, and drive towards it. You can use the depth information from the kinect to achieve the proper distance.

This also sounds like your homework.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0